# If the eigenvalues are distinct then the eigenspaces are all one dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Theorem: Diagonalizable matrices share the same eigenvector matrix $S$ iff $AB=BA$
>
> Proof: $(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $AB=BA$.
>
> $$ABx=BAx=B\lambda x=\lambda Bx$$
> Thus $x$ and $Bx$ are both eigenvectors of $A$, sharing the same $\lambda$.
> Assume that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct (it means the eigenspaces are all one dimensional) then $Bx$ must be a multiple of $x$. In other words $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ as well as $A$.

Above, I can't follow the meaning of "if the eigenvalues are distinct then the eigenspaces are all one dimensional".

For example, let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -5 \\ 2 & -3\end{pmatrix}$$
It has two distinct eigenvalues, $-1$ and $2$. But its eignevectors are $x_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 &1\end{pmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$ and $x_2=\begin{pmatrix}5 &2 \end{pmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$, they are not one dimensional.

Comment: In your example the eigenspace for - 1 is spanned by $(1,1)$. This means that it has a basis with only one vector. It has nothing to do with the number of components of your vectors.

Comment: vectors have no dimension, vector spaces have

Comment: one dimensional spaces may be more than points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"one dimensional" refers to the dimension of the *space of eigenvectors* for a particular eigenvalue.  All the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue -1 are multiples of $x_1$.  In other words, they are spanned by *one* vector, so the space of eigenvectors has dimension *one*.

Do not confuse this with the fact that $x_1 = (1,1)$ has 2 coordinates.  That just means that $x_1$ *lives* in a 2 dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or whatever your field is).  The space of eigenvectors is a subspace of that 2 dimensional space, and that subspace is 1 dimensional.

Comment: So that means the eigenspace consists of only one vector-$x_1$ or $x_2$, right? Thanks!

Comment: No.  The eigenspace consists of the set of vectors *spanned* by $x_1$ (or $x_2$), i.e., the multiples of $x_1$ (or $x_2$).  Remember that the eigenspace for a particular eigenvalue is always a subspace.

Comment: Set of vectors? Then, for example, 2$x_1$+3$x_1$ can span the eigenspace of $\lambda_1$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  The span of $x_1$ is the set of all multiples of $x_1$.  If an eigenspace is one dimensional, it will be spanned by any of the nonzero vectors in the eigenspace.